# Elasticsearch configure stemming for fields that can be french or english

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a Fr/En website, and I have a "profile" model, where information can be written in English OR in French (and I don't know which one). Consider a simple model on Mongoid

```
class Profile
  field :job_name
  field :company_name
end
```

I want an intelligent search on the job name that supports stemming. So basically I want an english+french analyser on that field

I believe I have figured something for the indexing part, where I analyse the field in both languages :

```
mapping do
  indexes :job_name, type: :string, fields: {
    french: { type: :string, analyzer: 'french' },
    english: { type: :string, analyzer: 'english' }
  }
end
```

I have problems configuring the stemming on the search. I'm actually not. My default search engine uses multi match with per-field boosting, and I don't really understand how to spcify the analysers on top of that :

```
query: {
  filtered: {
    query: {
      multi_match: {
        query: query,
        fields: [
          "company_name^3",
          "job_name^2",
        ],
        type: "best_fields",
        tie_breaker: 0.3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, when searching for "achat" (French for purchase), the engine should return results where the job name contains

- "gestionnaire d'achat" (see the "d'" prefix),
- "achats en gros" (see the plural).

And it should also work for similar english words

EDIT : My ES Index (is the "no" normal ?)

```
{
  "mydb": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "profile": {
        "properties": {
          "company_name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
          "job_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no",
            "fields": {
              "english": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "english"
              },
              "french": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "french"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1469789941429",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "HHN-rWTTStCXDgQtJMTEPg",
        "version": {
          "created": "2030499"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wildcard version for the field names and `multi_match` will use each sub-fields' analyzer for that:

```
      "fields": [
        "job_name.*^2"
      ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I tried creating someone with a job name "buyers of something", and `Profile.search('buyer')` didn't return any result... while it did with `buyers`

Comment: My suggestion is to test this with plain ES (`curl` or Sense) without your Ruby client because that is an additional variable. I just tested with `buyers of something` and the query works. For example, are you sure that the index mapping from Elasticsearch is the one you think it is? In your post you provided the Ruby code for it, but at Elasticsearch level that's the mapping?

Comment: For example, run `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/index_name/_mapping"` to get the mapping of the index.

Comment: I edited my question. Does the index structure look fine ?

Comment: The mapping looks ok. Check out my gist here: https://gist.github.com/astefan/fdfb128aec5bdeae654e09ac0d14ce93. Your test works for me.